# Getting inner text with HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, css, .net, html-agility-pack

I have the following [webpage](http://broinc.com/search.php?row=0&brocode=&stocknum=&submit=Find%20Item&text=&filter=all):

[image]

I am trying to grab the fields which have IDs and classnames:

```
        label =
            node.SelectSingleNode(
                ".//h3[@class='item_header']"
                ).InnerText.Replace("Label: ","").Trim();
        Console.WriteLine(label);
```

However, I am having a difficult time trying to figure out how to get the text here:

[image]

**How do you parse the text within tags that have no id's or class's such as  the following?**

```
<b>Label Cat. #: WEST 3007/8</b>
```

If it is at all helpful, here is the unique selector:

```
#\31 42248 > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > b:nth-child(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

The HTML Agility Pack has a companion CSS Selector library, where you could use the selector in your question to find the element.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack.CssSelectors/

Answer (score 0):

You have the ID of the table. You can just go from there.

```
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='142248']//b");

foreach (HtmlNode n in nodes)
{
    if (n.InnerText.ToLower().Contains("label"))
    {
         Console.WriteLine(n.InnerText);
    }
}
```

The xpath in the above code gives you all the  in the table with the id 142248.